# Непонятно сформулировано ограничение на удаление своих вопросов/ответов

Tags: дефект, поддержка, удаление-ответов

При попытке удалить свой ответ, всплывает следующее:

> *Вы удалили 5 своих сообщений сегодня; дальнейшее удаление заблокировано.
>
>   См. "Я переосмыслил свой вопрос; как его удалить?", чтобы узнать об альтернативных решениях.*

Во-первых, я переосмыслил свой **ответ**, а не вопрос, и теперь хочу удалить/скрыть его, в виду явной бесполезности для автора вопроса, ибо принят ответ другого участника.

```
"Очевидно — копипаста,  
 А не ошибка перевода.  
 Лентяи..." © UModeL
```

Во-вторых, в Справке [написано](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers):

> *Авторы ответов могут удалить их в **любое** время, кроме случаев, когда
>   ответ был принят автором вопроса.*

Вопрос: разве всплывшее ограничение не расходится с буквами правил?

Comment: Не расходится. Чтобы расходилось надо "вы можете удалять вопросы только с 3 до 5 по гринвичу".

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос: разве всплывшее ограничение не расходится с буквами правил?

Строго говоря, нет. Справка говорит о том, что вы можете удалить некоторый абстрактный ответ в любое время - и эта информация верна. О том, что число ответов, которые можно удалить в день, дополнительно ограничено, она просто умалчивает. Естественно, сразу возникает вопрос, почему и следует ли это изменить? По мне так это абсолютно правильно, так как легального сценария, в котором участнику нужно это знать, не существует. Массовое удаление ответов это либо вандализм, либо непонимание работы сайта. Ваш вопрос, видимо, демонстрирует второе, так как вы собрались удалять ответ "ибо принят ответ другого участника", что довольно странно. Часто бывает, что на вопрос дано несколько ответов, которые по разному отвечают на него, но принят из них только один, который автор посчитал лучшим. Это само по себе не значит, что другие ответы бесполезны. Галку принятого ответа автор может и переставить, поэтому бросаться удалять ответы только по этой причине бессмысленно.

Таким образом, текст справки по удалению ответов должен остаться как есть. Единственная настоящая проблема тут в том, что ошибка при удалении ответа не должна отправлять на страницу "Я переосмыслил свой вопрос..." - она не даст в данном случае "альтернативного решения". Это нужно поправить, либо через предложение изменить исходную строку на MSE, либо, на худой конец, через редактирование нашего перевода.